# category url without https redirect to homepage in magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect

we have enabled https in our website and enabled 301 in admin section.

But the issue is with the category urls. Suppose if we select http:// www.testsite.com/ category.html, it will redirect to homepage. So after some searching i found a solution, which told me to add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

after 
`RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`
in .htaccess

Now this url http:// www.testsite.com/ category.html redirects to https:// www.testsite.com/ category.html.
But for this url http:// testsite.com/ category.html, it redirects to homepage. I think some tweak on the above code is required. Could anybody help me in this please.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're simply trying to force the WWW and force the HTTPS. While this should typically be done inside of a virtualhost configuration, I can understand if that's not an option.

The solution is simple, and is as follows:

```
# Start the Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

#Set the base url to / unless you're in a subdirectory, so not modify this.
RewriteBase /

#Redirect all requests to WWW.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testsite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.testsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# If requests are made on port 80, rewrite to HTTPS which will server over port 443.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://testsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

If you're looking to only redirect specific subdirectories, or pages, simply append the path to the condition and rules above.